# What does fit to coordinate do in react-native-maps

Tags: typescript, react-native, google-maps, apple-maps

Can someone tell me what does `fitToCoordinates` do in React native (react-native-maps)?

react-native-maps have mentioned this in their docs

```
| `fitToCoordinates` | `coordinates: Array<LatLng>, options: { edgePadding: EdgePadding, animated: Boolean }` | If called in `ComponentDidMount` in android, it will cause an exception. It is recommended to call it from the MapView `onLayout` event.
```

Which I am unable to comprehend.

I have simple code in which marker is always centered in the screen

```
const updateLocationCordinate = (e:MapEvent) => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = e.nativeEvent.coordinate
    setLocationData({
      ...locationData, 
      latitude,
      longitude
    })
  }
return
 <MapView 
      loadingEnabled={true}
        style={styles.map} 
        provider="google"
        region={{
          latitude, 
          longitude, 
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA, 
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }}
      >
          <Marker 
            draggable
            coordinate={{
              latitude, 
              longitude
            }}
            title="Me"
            onDragEnd={updateLocationCordinate}
          />
      </MapView>
```

Why would I or people use `fitToCoordinates` and what does this exactly.

Super helpful if someone can explain with some examples.

Answer (score 2):

`fitToCoordinates` is used so that all the coordinates you passed in your coordinates array fits on the view on the map. So if you have multiple coordinates in in your array, it will make sure that it will be included in the view of your map.

Here's an [example of a code](https://snack.expo.dev/0MpiZ39vE) wherein, fitToCoordinates are used so that you can see all the coordinates when you click the button. You can add coordinates in the coords array so that you can see how it works.

Note, after testing,I saw that if your coordinates are too far from each other and won't fit the lowest zoom level, it will only show the area around the center of those coordinates.

```
import React, { useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Modal, Button } from 'react-native';

import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker,Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

export default function App() {
  const position = {
    latitude: 51,
    longitude: -0.48,
  };

   const [coords, setCoords] = useState([
    { latitude: 37.766155, longitude: -122.51058 },
    { latitude: 37.7948605, longitude: -122.4596065 },
    { latitude: 37.799476, longitude: -122.397995 },
  ]);


  const map = useRef();

  async function fitMapToPolyline() {

map.current.fitToCoordinates(coords, {
      edgePadding: {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 20,
      },
    });


  }

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <Modal animationType={'slide'} visible={true}>
        <MapView
          ref={map}
          style={[style.map]}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.7948605,
            longitude: -122.4596065,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}>
       {coords.map((coords, index) => (
            <Marker key={index} coordinate={coords} />
          ))}
          <Polyline
            coordinates={coords}
            strokeColor={'rgb(0, 0, 0)'}
            strokeWidth={6}
          />
        </MapView>
        <View style={style.button}>
          <Button title={'Fit map to see whole Polyline'} onPress={fitMapToPolyline} />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}


const style = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 100,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey @Pagemag, thanks for your answer. I was curious is there any method I can use to get the zoom level result of fitToCoordinate method (latLong delta)?